# "{"code":-1002,"msg":"You are not authorized to execute this request."}" - В чем может быть проблема API Biinance?

Tags: php, signature, binance

```
    if ($stmt_check->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Transaction already deposited";

    // signature

    $api_key = 'x';
    $secret_key = 'z';

    $fromAsset = $send_currency;
    $toAsset = $receive_currency;
    $fromAmount = $send_value;
    $toAmount = $receive_amount;

    $timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

    $params = [
        'fromAsset' => $fromAsset,
        'toAsset' => $toAsset,
        'fromAmount' => $fromAmount,
        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
    ];
    
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', http_build_query($params), $secret_key);
    
    $params['signature'] = $signature;
    
    $url = 'https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/convert/getQuote';
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?' . http_build_query($params) . '&signature=' . $signature);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-MBX-APIKEY: ' . $api_key,
    ]);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($response);
    
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);
    
    if ($response !== false) {
        $quote_response = json_decode($response, true);
        if (isset($quote_response['quoteId'])) {
            // Process the quote response as needed
        } else {
            echo "Error: Unable to get quote from Binance API";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to Binance API";
    }
```

Есть фрагмент кода PHP который должен выполнять обмен крипто активов, но выдается ошибка которую я указал в названии вопроса. все нужные права у api есть.